# extract line of image (matrix)

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I load images in matlab and work with them as double matrices.

Now I want to extract the data values across a straight line from one point of the image to another. This line  however does not equal to a column or row (that would be easy).

How can I do that with matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A line obeys the eq of the line `y=a*x+b`. Here x and y are coordiantes of the image. So if you want a line defined by two points `(x1,y1) -> (x2,y2)`, the slope `a` is `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` and `b=y1-a*x1`. So next , select points in the matrix the obey the eq of the line as follows:

Create data and end points:

```
m=peaks(50);
x1=5 ; x2=42;
y1=21; y2=29;
```

calculate ew of line parameters:

```
a=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
b=y1-a*x1;
```

define the line:

```
x=x1:x2;
y=round(a*x+b);
```

select the proper matrix elements using linear indexing:

```
ind=sub2ind(size(m),y,x)
```

plot:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
imagesc(m); hold on
colormap(bone)
line([x1 x2],[y1 y2],'Color',[1 0 0]);

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(m(ind))
```

[image]

Comment: Works very well! However the calculation of a is wrong (x and y reversed): `a=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);`

Comment: already corrected that (in the code but not in the explanation)... thanks for noticing. now corrected.